# Выбор хостинга

Tags: hosting, хостинг

Здравствуйте.

Предложите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь не очень дорогой и хороший хостинг.
И стоит ли покупать хостинг на 2domians от reg.ru [ХОСТИНГ](https://reg.2domains.ru/hosting/order.php)?

Пожелания:

1. Более 1000 Мб памяти.
2. Бесконечный трафик.
3. База mysql.
4. FTP доступ.
5. Парковка домена с настройкой своих DNS.
6. Панель управления cPanel.
7. php 5.2, 5.3.
8. phpMyAdmin.
9. Цена не более 200 руб.

**НАШЕЛ ХОРОШИЙ ХОСТИНГ REG.RU**

Comment: @cnofss, для того, чтоб вам могли что-либо порекомендовать, нужно описать то, чего вы ждёте от хостинга, его минимальные параметры и возможности, которые вам потребуются для нормальной работы. И словосочетание "не очень дорогой" - понятие растяжимое. Для кого-то и 100$ в месяц не дорого.

Comment: Изменил, все что надо, написал.

Comment: @cnofss, всё бы ничего, если не последний пункт. За такую сумму, я практически уверен, что вы не найдёте нормальный хостинг. Или же напоритесь на реселлеров "в третьем колене", которые расскажут вам одно, а получите только часть от рассказанного.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я долгое время использовал [Teli](http://www.teli.ru/thosting.htm), да и сейчас продолжаю использовать. За 200 рублей в месяц 2гб памяти, неограниченный траффик и количество сайтов/БД, полная настройка DNS, Cpanel, высокий аптайм.
Но когда общее количество сайтов перевалило за 30, посещаемость суммарная была неслабая, его конечно перестало хватать.

Comment: Вы хотели сказать: "2Гб дискового пространства", а не памяти.

Comment: При оплате на год выгоднее получается smartape.ru (нет cpanel, но у них админка годная вполне). Пользовался Teli года два назад - не понравился сапорт и сайты падали периодически.

Comment: Мне на месяц сейчас хоть какой нибудь надо, потом нормальный возьму, если сайт нормально прорекламирую. А Teli вообще нормальный или нет? Быстрый? Ну или просто, если не сложно, напишите плюсы и минусы.

Comment: @Deonis, так я выражаюсь, как автор. Думаю, и так понятно, что 1гб оперативы за 200 рублей в месяц никто не даст. Это надо VPS уже искать..

@Лисёнок, я редко в саппорт обращался. Но мои мелкие проблемки решали всегда. Насчёт падания сайтов — у меня такое было очень редко, думаю, не чаще, чем у других.

@cnofss, я имел дело с популярными хостингами типа Руцентра, 1Gb, Майордомо — по-моему, они по удобству рядом не стоят с Teli. Админки везде самописные, неудобные, мало возможностей. Везде ограничения по количеству сайтов, БД. Teli в этом плане как раз порадовал анлимом и cPanel.

Comment: Насчёт быстроты не знаю. У меня там висело порядка 30 сайтов на MODx Evolution, и под конец только стало тормозить, когда стал добавлять на сайты функционал, требующий больших мощностей. Ну и сайты на LiveStreet не славились быстродействием. Тут вопрос в оптимизации..

Ну из недостатков основных у Teli — отсутствие SSH. Хотя я сам не пользуюсь.

Comment: Полазил на 2domians и нашел отличный хост. reg.ru - не дорого и вполне выгодно вроде) Ну вам все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) - одна из передовых площадок по соотношению цена/качество, предоставляющих VPS (т.е. админить придется руками, но по деньгам это выйдет дешевле некоторых shared-хостингов).

Comment: Добавлю ко вполне справедливой правке Etki моего ответа, что админить руками в DO одно удовольствие, поскольку на сайте подробные мануалы https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials , так что это скорее плюс.

Comment: Не смог разобраться. ЧЧто нибудь другое есть?

Comment: @cnofss, с чем возникли трудности?